# How do I solve this function using basic instructions?

Tags: computability, automata

The function $f$ takes two integers and produces one integer

$f(a,b) \vdash 3*(b-a)$

The only instructions I can use are `+1`, `-1`, and `go to loop`

At a high level, I know how to write $z = 3*(a,b)$

Comment: Go to is uncondintional jump (`JMP`)? or tests for zero (`JZ`)? If first, could you test anything?

Comment: What does "solve this function" mean?  What is your question?  What does the "+1" instruction do?